# Data from 3 tables with a primary key in common

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables `Invoice`, `Account` and `Visits`

Each has a primary key in common (`AccountID`). I need to draw data for accounts that have not had a visit in the month of july and had a valid account to allow a visit in that month (drawn from `Invoice` - `scheduletype` and `Account` - `startdate`)

I have tried using several joins but am not able to get the data out as I need it and am fairly new to SQL. Would anyone be able to help me out with some pointers please?

Comment: Account table structure:
AccountID Memberid AccountTemplateID RestrictID Barcode IsTerm StartDate EndDate AdfitRef Term ConTotal ConBalance ClubStop AccDescription AccType WhoUpdate LastUpdate Notes BankInfo OldBarcode LoadDate CardPrinted StopNote CCExpiry Renewal IsDeleted SetTotal TermType AccountGroup Branchid CCType SalesPerson

Comment: Invoice table structure" InvoiceID AccountID HoldPayments ScheduleType StartDate EndDate Installment Frequency WKInstallment DueNow GraceDueNow WhoUpdate LastUpdate AdfitID BillNext WKElapsed IsDeleted MemberID CurrentOffsetUnit CurrentOffset OriginalOffset
OriginalOffsetUnit Description RunningPaymentValue DailyValue MonthlyValue IsLocked

Comment: Visits table structure: VisitID BranchID MemberID AccountID Visit EntryZone Points Status ClubStop StopNote DueNow GraceOverdue ConBalance OtherClubStop OtherGraceOverdue BookingId BookingDate BookingDescription SessionId SessionDate SessionDescription Birthday
IsConcession Restriction DateOutside DueToExpire AccountExpired ActivityId ActivityDescription ActivityDate Overdue OtherOverdue
Reciprocal HomeBranchID

Comment: Relevant columns are the startdate and enddate in account which needs to include people who have had an active account in July while having no start and end date in the invoice table during july and no scheduletype of hold for that time and also had no visit during this time from the visits table (visit being the date field in visits table)

Comment: Which date in the Visits table is the visit date? SessionDate or ActivityDate?

Comment: Thanks for your help John, got the data I needed out with help from your report, the visit column is actually the datetime field I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing with the Visit date,

```
SELECT  a.AccountID
FROM    Account a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS  (
                    SELECT 1 
                    FROM Invoice i 
                    WHERE i.AccountID = a.AccountID 
                    AND i.ScheduleType = 'hold'
                    AND i.StartDate < '8/1/2012'
                    AND i.EndDate >= '7/1/2012'
                    )
AND     NOT EXISTS  (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM Visits v
                    WHERE v.AccountID = a.AccountID
                    AND v.SessionDate >= '7/1/2012'
                    AND v.SessionDate < '8/1/2012'                  
                    )
AND     a.StartDate < '8/1/2012'
AND     a.EndDate >= '7/1/2012'
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select A.*
from Accounts A
where A.AccountID NOT IN
    (Select V.AcocountID
     From Visits V
     Where V.date like '%July%'   //replace by appropriate condition
    ) AND
     A.AccountID IN
    (Select I.AccountID
     From Invoice I
     Where I.type = Invoice        //replace by appropriate condition
    ) AND
    A.startDate< July              //replace by appropriate condition
```

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from the previous answer, you can do it like this too (I prefer using EXISTS to see if the AccountID is in there - if there are any, it stops looking immediately).

```
SELECT A.* FROM Accounts A WHERE A.AccountID NOT IN
    (SELECT V.AccountID
        FROM Visits V
        WHERE CONVERT(date, V.date) BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-07-31'
        -- assuming V.date is a 'datetime'. if V.date is already a 'date' then:
        -- WHERE V.date BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-07-31'
        -- or you could say
        -- WHERE NOT(DATEPART(month, V.date) = '7' AND DATEPART(year, V.date) = '2012')
    )
    AND EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM Invoice I
        WHERE I.type = Invoice        //or whatever
    ) AND
    A.startDate < '2012-07-01'        //or whatever
```

Comment: in the exist subquery don't you have to check I.AccountID = V.accountID?

Answer (score 0):

Use below query :

```
Select A.*
From Accounts A
left join visits v on v.AccountID = A.AccountID 
                  AND v.SessionDate >= '2012-07-01'
                  AND v.SessionDate < '2012-08-01'
left join Invoice I ON I.AccountID = A.AccountID
                   AND I.ScheduleType = 'hold'
Where V.AccountID IS NULL
   and I.AccountID IS NULL
   and A.startDate < '2012-07-01'
```